# How to change a form's data after already populating it in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

This might be a duplicate but I tried lots of solutions and none worked for me.

views.py

```
class signup_view(View):
def get(self, request):
    signup_form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {"forms": signup_form})

def post(self, request):
    signup_form = SignUpForm(data=request.POST)
    if signup_form.is_valid():
        email = signup_form.cleaned_data.get('user_email')
        password = signup_form.cleaned_data.get('user_pass')
        print("Original password is: ", password)
        hashed_password = make_password(password)
        print("Hashed password is: ", hashed_password)
        signup_form.inital['user_pass'] = hashed_password 
        signup_form.save()
        request.session['username'] = email
        return render(request, 'main_page.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'signup.html', {"forms": signup_form})
```

I have this django view that I populate with information from the post request, however, I need to make sure that both the password and the password confirmation (in the forms) are the same so that I can procced, I do that in the clean() function I'll post below. However, I need to save the hashed password on my database and not the actual password and I have no idea what I can do the change the contents of the form after I already verified that it's valid (not sure if I can even do this).

```
class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
user_pass_check = forms.CharField(label="Password confirmation", widget=forms.PasswordInput())
class Meta:
    model = AppUser
    fields = ["user_email", "user_country", "user_pass"]
    widgets = {"user_pass": forms.PasswordInput()}

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(SignUpForm, self).clean()
    pass1 = cleaned_data.get('user_pass_check')
    pass2 = cleaned_data.get('user_pass')
    if pass1 != pass2:
        raise forms.ValidationError("The two password fields must match.")
    return cleaned_data
```

Any help would be amazing, been struggling with this for hours.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how to do it. Instead, get the model object by saving with commit=False and then setthe password on that object before saving for real.

```
user = signup_form.save(commit=False)
user.user_pass = hashed_password 
user.save()
```

However, I hope that you are not rolling your own authentication. This is a thing that **you must not do**, even if you are correctly hashing passwords. There are plenty of other security gotchas involved in auth, and Django has already tested these. Don't do this. Use the built-in authentication framework, and substitute your own User object if you need to.

Comment: Thank you! As you feared I was using my own auth system because I had some extra stuff I needed for my user to have but since you're reccomending using the django User object I'll switch to that, I'm sure there's a way to add extra fields to the User object.
I wasn't really bothered by using my custom user object since this is a school project and the focus isn't in this specific issue, but it is good django practice so thank you very much for pointing that out!